# xpath expression fails with checking attribute value

Tags: java, xpath

I need to get every **operator_id** tags attribute **@name** in **group** tag with **@title** attribute equals some string, 
an example below fails to do this:

```
List list = doc.selectNodes("//root//menu//group[@title=" + menuTitle + "]//operator_id//@name");
```

XML Structure:

```
  <group id="980" title="Переводы" image="" sh_n="1" enable="1" visible="0" image_bg="" type="">
  <operator_id id="10000047" name="Перевод физ лицу" image="individual.png" sh_n="1" enable="1" visible="1" /> 
  <operator_id id="10000048" name="Перевод юр лицу" image="organizations.png" sh_n="1" enable="1" visible="1" /> 
  <operator_id id="10000078" name="Перевод внутри банка" image="innerbank.png" sh_n="1" enable="1" visible="1" /> 
  <operator_id id="10000049" name="Налоговый платеж" image="taxes1.png" sh_n="1" enable="1" visible="1" /> 
  </group>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an XPath expert by any means, but I don't *think* you want to use double-slashes all the way through your query. Have you tried:

```
List list = doc.selectNodes(
   "//root/menu/group[@title=" + menuTitle + "]/operator_id/@name");
```

? Even the `//` at the start can be just `/` if it's really meant to be the root element.

Additionally, I suspect you should add quoting for the value, e.g.

```
List list = doc.selectNodes(
   "//root/menu/group[@title='" + menuTitle + "']/operator_id/@name");
```

or

```
List list = doc.selectNodes(
   "//root/menu/group[@title=\"" + menuTitle + "\"]/operator_id/@name");
```

Those would be more like the samples in the XPath specification.

Comment: Yeah I've already tried it out and it works - thank U for response.